# Ways to implement "Attribute Based Access Control" with GraphQL

Tags: security, authorization, graphql, abac

While GraphQL mentions security should be delegated to underlying business logic, the nature of GraphQL lends itself very well to security.

In GraphQL the Query can have a resolve method, also each field can have a resolve method. In a way we are traversing the graph, if we provide resolvers for each query and all fields of their results.

Now "Attribute Based Access Control" is gaining popularity with its ways to define security policy across

- Subject
- Resource
- Action
- Environment

One way "Attribute Based Access Control" is implemented is, that it modifies the query being fired to only fetch eligible data. This could be done by a wrapper resolver.

Second way "Attribute Based Access Control" can be implement in GraphQL, is to use field level resolvers to decide whether to expose that field or not.

The question I have to the community is what are the various ways to implement "Attribute Based Access Control" in GraphQL, especially leveraging the strengths of GraphQL

Cheers,
Rohit

Comment: https://github.com/kriasoft/nodejs-api-starter/issues/78

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways ABAC could be used to secure data - be it GraphQL; SQL; HQL... - like you say:

1. Either you modify the incoming query so that the modified query only retrieves the entitled data. This is for instance how some database proxies work. It intercepts `'SELECT a, b, c FROM t'` and converts it into `'SELECT a, b, c FROM t WHERE...'` Axiomatics does that with its Data Access Filter.
2. Or you configure the underlying system so that it only allows access under the right circumstances. We call that provisioning. Years ago, for instance, MySQL had a feature called FGAC - fine-grained access control that could be used to that effect.

The benefit of 1. is that it is unintrusive. It sits in front of the data source and could in principle work for several types of data sources e.g. SQL, GraphQL... The benefit of 2. is that you do not need the proxy component and the configuration is native to the target system.

In any case, yes Graph databases lend themselves really well to ABAC because of the relationship between the different entities. In a way, relational databases have that too but perhaps not as obvious.